# Editing Code for CMS *** Fixed - my own stupidity - I appologise and thank everyone for their help

Tags: cms

edited question... I feel people may be misunderstanding my question, so i apologise for any ambiguity

[image]

As you can see from the above picture, I have text in the top left hand corner of the CMS.

This text is the same on every page and I feel it is having a negative effect on the running of the CMS.

I have no clue how it got there and as a result have no clue how to get rid of it

I have a feeling I have managed to insert code as text in a php script but am unsure which one as I only eve open scripts related to my child theme.

Does anyone have any idea which scripts may link directly to the CMS and cause the above?

Comment: you need to locate where that line is in your code and make sure there are <?php tags around it

Comment: The only place i had ever put it was in functions.php. So i can't understand why it is showing here like this?

Comment: you probably put it in a wrong place

Comment: yip :-(.  I was keen to know if anyone knew where that wrong place might be? I didnt know I could do anything direct to the CMS :-s lol

Comment: why don't you put the code that you added up here so we can see what you did?

Comment: The code that is in the picture is all I put in - add_filter('pwb-single-product-brands '_'return_false') -... I added that to the bottom of fuctions.php then deleted it when I realised that it wasnt working. I have no idea how it ended up showing on the CMS

Answer (score 1):

To have full control over what is displayed on each page, you'd do best to [create a Child Theme](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/). Basically, you create a `style.css` file with specific comments at the top, so WordPress recognizes your files as a theme. Then, you copy any of WooCommerce's files where you need customization, and place them into your child theme. You can then edit the PHP in just those files to remove things like the brand.

As to your code snippet, any PHP must be wrapped inside `<?php ... ?>` tags or the server won't recognize it as PHP. So add `<?php` and `?>` around `add_filter`, like so:

```
<?php add_filter( 'pwb-single-product-brands', _'return_false'); ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="ie8 wp-toolbar"  lang="en-US">
 <![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 8) ]><!-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="wp-toolbar"  lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
```

But, normally you don't use `add_filter` inside the same file where your DOCTYPE and basic HTML start - those are usually in your theme's `header.php` file, and filters belong ideally in a plugin, or second-best in a child theme's `functions.php` file.

Comment: Thank you for your reply elaine.    The part i am trying to remove ia not actually on my webpage. It shiws at the top of the wordpress cms in my admin.   I had trued to edit a page and somehow the code ended up there and shows on the cms as words at the top. I will post a picture when im home